# TYPO3 extension generate view error

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm building my first TYPO3 extension, exactly I'm just trying to build the example that is on the TYPO3 page, see [link](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/Index.html). Looks like something in the controller goes wrong. I'm using the following code

```
class Tx_Mtclnt_Controller_AdsController
   extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController {

   public function listAction() {       

       $adsRepository = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_Mtclnt_Domain_Repository_AdsRepository');
       $ads = $adsRepository->findAll();
       $this->view->assign('ads', $ads);
   }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> 1: PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository::__construct() must implement interface TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface, none given, called in /home/mtclnt02/typo3_src-6.2.9/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 4431 and defined in /home/mtclnt02/typo3_src-6.2.9/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Repository.php line 75 (More information)
>
> TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception thrown in file
> /home/mtclnt02/typo3_src-6.2.9/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php in line 101.

Comment: Is this really 6.2 code ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get results from the repository, which you try to create. The class `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository` has a constructor, which requires `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface` as argument. Since you don't pass an objectManager class in your `t3lib_div::makeInstance`, the error is thrown. You can avoid this, by using dependeny injection like shown below.

```
/**
 * @var Tx_Mtclnt_Domain_Repository_AdsRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $adsRepository;

public function listAction() {
  $adsRepository = $this->adsRepository->findAll();
}
```

But I also see a **general problem** here, because the Extbase / Fluid book you refer to is outdated on some topics. From my point of view, the refered book is a quite useful resource if you want to understand the **concept and architecture** of an Extbase/Fluid extension, but **not for code examples** any more, since a lot of things have changed in TYPO3 since the book has been written.

If you want to start with TYPO3 extension development for TYPO3 6.2 or higher, I would suggest you install the extension [extension builder](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) and use it to create your first extension. The manual contains a short but helpful [users manual](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/extension_builder/User/Index.html), which guides you through the basics of creating a simple TYPO3 extension.

After you created your first extension with extension builder, you can go some steps further by adding functionality to the code created by extension builer.

Comment: Thanks for the clear anwser, I will start working with the extension builder!